# Problema al redimensionar una imagen con php

Tags: php, html, img, gd

Estoy tratando de redimensionar una imagen que se envia desde un form, todo con php.
Me guarda bien el name de la img en bd y redimensiona bien pero el tema es que me las guarda y muestra toda negra.

Estoy usando las funciones GD de php. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo para la redimensión es este

```
public function imagenes($file, $destino, $imagenAnt = null)
{
    $r = ['estado' => false, 'mensaje' => '', 'imagen' => ''];
    $f = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
    list($ancho_orig, $alto_orig) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);//Obtengo el tamaño de la imagen
    $ratio_orig = $ancho_orig/$alto_orig;
    $w=200;
    $h=200;
    
    $existe_destino = false;
    if(is_dir($destino)){
        $existe_destino = true;
    }else{
        if(@mkdir($destino, 0777, true)) $existe_destino = true; 
    }
   
    if ($existe_destino) {
        if (!empty($file['name'])) {
            if (in_array($file['type'], $f)) {
                //Redimención de imagen
                if ($w/$h > $ratio_orig) {
                    $w = $h*$ratio_orig;
                 } else {
                    $h = $w/$ratio_orig;
                 }

                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
                $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $ancho_original, $alto_original);
                imagejpeg($dst, $file['tmp_name'],100);
                
                

                $nn = uniqid();
                
                // if ($re) {
                if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destino.$nn.'.'.$ext)){
                    $r['imagen']    = $nn.'.'.$ext;
                    $r['mensaje']   = __("La imagen se subió correctamente");
                    $r['estado']    = true;
                    $r['size']      = $file['size'];

                    if(!empty($imagenAnt)){
                        if($imagenAnt != "default.png"){
                            @unlink($destino.$imagenAnt);
                        }
                    }
                }else{ $r["mensaje"] = __("Ocurrió un error al guardar imagen."); }
            }else{ $r["mensaje"] = __("El formato de imagen es incorrecto."); }
        }else{ $r["mensaje"] = __("La imagen no se subió correctamente."); }
    }else{ $r["mensaje"] = __("La carpeta donde intenta guardar la imagen, no existe y no pudo ser creada."); }
    
    return $r;
}
```

No entiendo cual es el problema sospecho que puede ser el manejo del $file[tmp_name] , espero me puedan ayudar .
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si la imagen subida no es jpg? No estás analizando el tipo de imagen y, sin embargo, siempre usarás `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías probar cambiando las lineas.

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $ancho_original, $alto_original);
imagejpeg($dst, $file['tmp_name'],100);
```

Por:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
$dst = imagescale($src, $w, $h, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED);
imagejpeg($dst, $file['tmp_name'], 100);
```

Espero poder ayudarte.

Según la página de php.net el método imageScale redimensiona una imagen empleando el algoritmo de interpolación dado y tiene varios modos de interpolación: IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED, IMG_BICUBIC, IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED.

IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED : Implementación de punto fijo de la interpolación bilinear (predeterminado (también en la creación de imágenes)).

Algunas características.

Características de interpolación nearest:

- Es un método básico.
- Requiere un tiempo de procesado bajo.
- Solo tiene en cuenta un píxel: el más cercano al punto interpolado.
- Simplemente aumenta el tamaño de cada píxel.

Características de interpolación Bilineal:

- Tiene en cuenta los valores en los píxeles conocidos que rodean a uno dado en una vecindad de los 2x2 píxeles más cercanos.
- Se toma el promedio ponderado de estos 4 píxeles y se calcula el valor interpolado.
- El resultado está más suavizado que las imágenes obtenidas utilizando el método del píxel más cercano.
- Necesita más tiempo de procesado.

Características de interpolación bicúbica :

- Un paso más allá del caso bilineal es considerar la vecindad de los 4x4 píxeles conocidos más cercanos, es decir, un total de 16 píxeles.
- Como están situados a distancias distintas del píxel de valor desconocido, se da mayor peso en el cálculo a los más cercanos.
- Produce imágenes más nítidas que los dos métodos anteriores.
- Es un buen compromiso entre tiempo de procesado y calidad de resultado.

Comment: Que utilidad tiene ese 'IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED'?

Comment: He actualizado la publicación, espero que aclare tu pregunta.